# Make two dimensional arrays of similar length in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a 2 dimensional array like this

```js
[[Date(), 1],[Date(), 3], [Date(), 5]]

[[Date(), 5],[Date(), 2]]

[[Date(), 7],[Date(), 3], [Date(), 1], [[Date(), 4],[Date(), 7], [Date(), 3]]]
```

The output should be like this

```js
[[Date(), 1],[Date(), 3], [Date(), 5], [Date(), 5], [Date(), 5], [Date(), 5]]

[[Date(), 5],[Date(), 2], [Date(), 2], [Date(), 2], [Date(), 2], [Date(), 2]]

[[Date(), 7],[Date(), 3], [Date(), 1], [[Date(), 4],[Date(), 7], [Date(), 3]]]
```

It should add last element to the arrays with lesser lengths and form a two dimensional array with same length

Comment: Isnt it just finding out max length and padding other arrays with last element ?

Comment: _"The output should be like this"_... the output of _what_?

Comment: Are the padded elements meant to be copies of the last item or references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the criteria of your question is not completely clear, the code below produces the output that you described from the input that you described.

A key consideration is that you must count the number of `[Date instance, number]` tuples in each array when comparing lengths (not each array's length) because the final array includes a sub-array of tuples as its last element.

```js
function isTuple (value) {
  return (
    Array.isArray(value)
    && value.length === 2
    && value[0] instanceof Date
    && typeof value[1] === 'number'
  );
}

function countTuples (array) {
  let count = 0;

  for (const element of array) {
    if (isTuple(element)) {
      count += 1;
      continue;
    }
    else if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      count += countTuples(element);
      continue;
    }
    throw new Error('Unexpected value');
  }

  return count;
}

const arr1 = [[new Date(), 1], [new Date(), 3], [new Date(), 5]];
const arr2 = [[new Date(), 5], [new Date(), 2]];
const arr3 = [[new Date(), 7], [new Date(), 3], [new Date(), 1], [[new Date(), 4], [new Date(), 7], [new Date(), 3]]];

const arrays = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
const tupleCounts = arrays.map(array => countTuples(array));
const maxLength = Math.max(...tupleCounts);

for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i += 1) {
  const count = tupleCounts[i];
  if (count === maxLength) continue;
  const array = arrays[i];
  const lastElement = array.at(-1);
  while (array.length < maxLength) array.push(lastElement);
}

const readableOutput = arrays.map(
  array => array
    .flat(Infinity)
    .filter(value => typeof value === 'number')
    .join(', ')
).join('\n');

console.log(readableOutput);
console.log(arrays);
```

If you don't want to create duplicate references to the final tuple in each not-longest array, you can replace the line with the while loop so that new tuples are created instead:

```js
// Before
while (array.length < maxLength) array.push(lastElement);

// After
while (array.length < maxLength) {
  array.push([new Date(lastElement[0]), lastElement[1]]);
}
```

```js
function isTuple (value) {
  return (
    Array.isArray(value)
    && value.length === 2
    && value[0] instanceof Date
    && typeof value[1] === 'number'
  );
}

function countTuples (array) {
  let count = 0;

  for (const element of array) {
    if (isTuple(element)) {
      count += 1;
      continue;
    }
    else if (Array.isArray(element)) {
      count += countTuples(element);
      continue;
    }
    throw new Error('Unexpected value');
  }

  return count;
}

const arr1 = [[new Date(), 1], [new Date(), 3], [new Date(), 5]];
const arr2 = [[new Date(), 5], [new Date(), 2]];
const arr3 = [[new Date(), 7], [new Date(), 3], [new Date(), 1], [[new Date(), 4], [new Date(), 7], [new Date(), 3]]];

const arrays = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
const tupleCounts = arrays.map(array => countTuples(array));
const maxLength = Math.max(...tupleCounts);

for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i += 1) {
  const count = tupleCounts[i];
  if (count === maxLength) continue;
  const array = arrays[i];
  const lastElement = array.at(-1);
  // while (array.length < maxLength) array.push(lastElement);
  while (array.length < maxLength) {
    array.push([new Date(lastElement[0]), lastElement[1]]);
  }
}

const readableOutput = arrays.map(
  array => array
    .flat(Infinity)
    .filter(value => typeof value === 'number')
    .join(', ')
).join('\n');

console.log(readableOutput);
console.log(arrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we should get the longest array's length, assume they are called arr1, arr2, arr3

```
const maxLength = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length, arr3.length)
```

repeat this on each array

```
if (arr1.length < maxLength) {
 let tempArr = [...arr1]; // make a copy so the loop won't be changed in the middle of the way

 for (let i = arr1.length ; i < maxLength ; i++) {
  tempArr.push(arr1[arr1.length - 1]); // this will push the last item of arr1 into the next index
 }

 arr1 = tempArr; // you can apply the result back to the original variable or any others variable depends on what you need
}
```

Hope this help